# double click in for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, double-click

I have a simple python program that reads the input of a hid device from a for-loop.
I wan't to implement different actions (long, single, double, tripple press) for a single button.

The problem with my solution is that, compared to all other solutions I've seen, my loop only gets triggered if a button is pressed. That means that I can't simply call a function with a time constrain, because I would never trigger the single click.

I think I need a thread for this. But I'm not sure and don't know how I could do that.
Any help appreciated!

This is what I tried:

```
clicked = False
def set_clicked():
    global clicked
    clicked = True


click_registered = False
click_time = time.time()
def click_handler():
    global click_registered, clicked, click_time

    if click_registered and time.time() - click_time > 0.35:
        click_registered = False
        print("single")

    if clicked:
        if click_registered:
            if time.time() - click_time < 0.35:
                click_registered = False
                print("double")
        else:
            click_registered = True
        clicked = False
        click_time = time.time()


for event in device.read_loop(): # loops forever
    if event.code == 1:  # button pressed
        set_clicked()

    click_handler()
```

If there is other action after a single click, the loop is not triggered and neither will the single click.

I came up with the following as a possible solution for detecting a double click. But that still feels not quite right. Anybody having an elegant solution for that?

```
import threading
import time

press_count = 0
def thread_function(name):
    global press_count
    start_time = time.time()
    
    while time.time() - start_time < 0.35:
        if press_count == 2:
            press_count = 0
            print("double")
            return
    print("single")
    press_count = 0
    return

for n in range(3):
    if len(threading.enumerate()) >= 1:
        press_count+=1

    if len(threading.enumerate()) == 1:
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
        t.start()

    if n == 0:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if n == 1:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: You are calling `click_handler()` in a loop from inside itself, are you sure? In any case, every double click starts with a single click, so at the time you receive a single click, you can not possibly decide which of the two it's going to be. You can decide that after a certain threshold timespan though. For that, I'd use a `select()`-based loop, which is simpler than using another thread.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt you are right. Sorry, my mistake. I removed everything unrelated to my question and messed up the indentation. The for loop is actually not part of the click_handler. I changed that.

Comment: > In any case, every double click starts with a single click, so at the time you receive a single click, you can not possibly decide which of the two it's going to be.
True. My solution takes that into account. It "holds" the single click and only fires it after the time treshold. Except it is not fired if the loop is not triggered.